# Database periodic cleansing

Tags: mysql, database, cron

I'm creating a public messaging service and I was wondering, in order to perform a cleanse of the oldest messages, is it okay to delete the oldest message every time a new one is submitted? Or is this approach inefficient for some reason? If so, could you specify why?

I considered create a *Cron Job* for this, but I'm not sure if it applies in this case.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can schedule an event in MySQL:

```
DELIMITER $$

CREATE EVENT cleanup_messages ON SCHEDULE EVERY day ENABLE 
DO BEGIN
  DELETE FROM messages WHERE ......;
END $$

DELIMITER ;
```

http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/create-event.html

Answer (score 1):

That sounds *unlikely* to be appropriate. The appropriateness of removing an old message is unlikely to be dependent on the new message - for example, if you're meant to keep messages for at least a month, then you don't want to start deleting recent messages if you suddenly get a lot of messages in a short period.

I suggest you work out your "garbage" criteria and then schedule a regular job to batch delete old messages (e.g. once a day).

Comment: [Not entirely unlike](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Phrases_from_The_Hitchhiker's_Guide_to_the_Galaxy#Not_entirely_unlike)... Double negatives always make my head spin... But +1 for the _separation of concerns_...

Comment: @Jordão: Sorry, yes, I meant it sounds unlikely to be appropriate. Edited.

Answer (score 1):

I suggest Cron Job, I believe there is time stamp with each message so you can remove older post with help of time stamp on cron run.